# divide by count result in mysql

Tags: mysql, count, divide

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table1 WHERE user = "carl" AND ans = "yes"
```

then i want to divide the output of this query to another query, for example the output is 10. so it will be like:

```
10 / SELECT COUNT(*) From Table1 WHERE user = "carl"
```

How is the right syntax for this?

Thank You

Comment: `SELECT 10 / COUNT(*) FROM Table1 WHERE user = "carl" AND ans = "yes"`?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You want to use conditional aggregation and division.  You don't need two queries:

```
SELECT SUM(ans = 'yes')/COUNT(*)
FROM Table1
WHERE user = 'carl';
```

The `SUM(ans = 'yes')` counts the number of rows with `yes`.  Actually, you could further simplify this to:

```
SELECT avg(ans = 'yes')
FROM Table1
WHERE user = 'carl';
```

Comment: +1. Given the OP's specific queries this is an ideal solution.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this by running the two queries as sub-queries:

```
SELECT 
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table1 WHERE user = "carl" AND ans = "yes") / 
  (SELECT COUNT(*) From Table1 WHERE user = "carl")
```

Answer (score 2):

Do a

```
SELECT (10/COUNT(*)) AS `myVariable` FROM `Table1` WHERE...
```

Then use your `myVariable` as you need.